# Prompting user when viewing a website on an ipad to turn orientation to landscpape

Tags: web, responsive-design, orientation, device

I am wondering what I need to do when a user is viewing a website on an iPad / tablet device that they are prompted to rotate the iPad to landscape if it is in portrait mode.

I have done some research but don't seem to be able to find a clear answer. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you do that? Your website should adjust to the user's preferences, not the other way around.

Comment: I release this but its a short stop gap until i can sort all the little design bugs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.